# Reflexive property in protege

Tags: owl, semantic-web, ontology, protege

[This](https://ufile.io/rcv9m) is my ontology   created with protege 5  .

If i make `cl1` and `cl2` disjoint, then the ontology is being inconsistent , but if i uncheck `is_friend_of` reflexive , the ontology is not inconsistent any more . whats wrong with my ontology ?

I want only `cl1` class individuals have `is_friend_of` property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reflexivity of `:is_friend_of` is essential for inconsistency.

Take a look at *Reasoner > Inconsistent ontology explanation* :

[image: Inconsistency explanation]

I'll try to translate this explanation into (poor) English:

1. Since `:is_friend_of` is reflexive, then `:c2_inst :is_friend_of :c2_inst`.
2. Since the domain of `:is_friend_of` is `:cl1`, then `c2_inst rdf:type :cl1`.
3. Also, `c2_inst rdf:type :cl2`.
4. But `:cl1` and `:cl2` are disjoint — contradiction.

---

In fact, the domain of every reflexive property is `owl:Thing`.

As a workaround, you could uncheck reflexivity of `is_friend_of` and define `:cl1` in this way:

```
Class: cl1
    EquivalentTo: 
        is_friend_of some owl:Thing,
        is_friend_of some  Self
```

Comment: Thanks, you said `In fact, the domain of every reflexive property is owl:Thing` . why ? why i cant limit a reflexive property  domain to only one defined class as i do for other properties?

Comment: The reflexivity is a global property, it affects all individuals. If you want a local reflexivity, use `Self` as suggested in the answer.

Comment: @alex, see [this thread](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/protege-owl/2011-June/016877.html). Additionally, please use `has_friend` or something like instead of `is_friend_of`, it will be easier to understand. BTW, there are [inverse object properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-syntax-20121211/#Inverse_Object_Properties_2).

Comment: @alex Shouldn't `is_friend_of` be symmetric instead of reflexive?